# How to force Chrome or Firefox to always show bookmarks bar, even on sites that seem to request it hidden

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, bookmarks

For instance, if I try to log in at ea.com, a window pops up to https://connect.origin.com/us/ea/login?returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ea.com%2F, but my bookmarks bar is not visible in this window, and does not show when i use the keyboard shortcut, *despite the fact that I have commanded Chrome to **always** show the bookmarks bar* and this option is clearly checked in the View menu and under Settings.

This is a big problem because my keychain is a bookmarklet and I can't log in (at least not with a big pain) without the bookmarks bar being present.

I have the same problem in Firefox, so a solution for either browse would be nice.

edit: okay, apparently I can't just add a missing tag...

Comment: Isn't there a browser extension for your keychain?

Comment: not unless i write one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is proper behaviour deliberately supported by the browsers.
Other than [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html), where windows are described as having `type`s (normal, popup, panel, and app; but not explained) I can't seem to find any information on it.
But I believe you are experiencing a *secure window*.

What these are for is securing your otherwise open browser for that page. I've experienced this sort of thing with government pages where you have to fill out important forms; so on top of removing your bookmarks and extensions they wont let you view source, type into the address bar or even right click in some cases.

Basically there's nothing you can do about it, this isn't a hack EA has done to get the browser to behave this way, it's enforced by the browser itself. No add on or extension will have jurisdiction to override this.

Comment: very well. although, as it's my computer, i feel like i should have the jurisdiction and authority to override it. i'll look more into the page you have linked and the idea of a secure window to see what i can come up with.

Comment: well you do, the problem is it's the application that's doing it as a feature, it's not a setting. The only way to get around this would be to *write the application*, which, in the case of chrome, is actually not hard. Chromium is open source so you can edit the bits you want and compile your own custom 'chrome' browser with some of the security bits disabled if you're savvy

Comment: To reiterate, you have authority over how applications run with respect to what they let you (settings), you cant change any arbitrary behaviour (e.g. make MS calculator show '$' instead of '5'). This is why PUPs and trojans are a pain, some of them could be useful, but the fact there's no 'disable malicious activities' exposed by them you can't make them (you can only try to mitigate their effects or, you know, not use them)

Answer (score 0):

I found this searching for way to keep my tool bars open in Firefox, This is October 24, 2016 and you may have already solved, but in case not here is what I just now figured out, right click the 'open menu' at far right on the menu bar tool bar, then 'de-select/un-check' the 'Slim Chrome' option, then your toolbars are locked open for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but this is still an issue. I figure out Chrome, if you right click the top bar of the popup, you can choose "Show as Tab" which then brings the featureless popup window into a normal browser with tabs, making it so you can see the bookmark bar.

Comment: That doesn't happen for me. In fact, nothing happens when I right click.